# Where can I learn to fly in Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Once I reach level 90, where do I upgrade my flying skill so that I am able to fly over the island of Pandaria?

Is it possible to learn how to fly over Pandaria before I get to level 90 or is this restricted to max level characters only?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In order to fly in Pandaria, you need to learn "[Wisdom of the Four Winds](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=115913/wisdom-of-the-four-winds)". This can be learned from the flight trainer at your faction's city in the Vale of Eternal Blossoms:

[image: Vale of Eternal Blossoms map]

[Skydancer Shun](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=60167) is the flying trainer for the Horde and is located on the landing platform at the Shrine of Two Moons in the north.

[Cloudrunner Leng](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=60166) is the flying trainer for the Alliance and is located at the Shrine of Seven Stars in the south-east.

This ability can only be learned at level 90, thus it is not possible for you to fly in Pandaria until you're level 90, unless you have a level 90 friend with a two+ seater flying mount.

Comment: The map for the Horde city is WRONG. I wasted a ton of time trying to get there on foot.

Comment: @EnigmaQ not quite sure what you mean - the location circled in Red is indeed where the Huojin Pandaren are located, are you sure you were heading to the Shrine of TWo Moons and not Mogu'Shan Palace?

Comment: Note that you cannot travel here on foot directly from the Jade Forest zone. You will need to run around through the other zones the long way to get around the mountains. Or find a flight point that connects to the city.