# Where is the entrance to Mogu'shan Vaults?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Mogu'shan Vaults is the first raid instance of tier 14 in World of Warcraft: Mists of Pandaria. It is the first of three raid instances in this tier.

Where on Pandaria is the entrance to the instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mogu'shan Vaults is located in the north east of Kun-Lai Summit, on the Mogu'shan Terrace, overlooking the Zouchin Province at the foot of the mountain.

[image: Kun-Lai Summits]

This instance has its own summoning stone just outside the instance entrance, it appears that other than summoning this instance requires [wisdom of the four winds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85806/27134) to access the instance.

[image: Instance entrance]